# Прокрутка страницы до конкретного места

Tags: html, jquery, прокрутка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать прокрутку страницы до нижний границы конкретного  div, без всяких нажатий на кнопки, плавных прокруток и прочего? В моем проекте полно всякой всячины изза которой под подвалом сайта остается много места. Хочу реализовать прокрутку от верхней границы страницы до нижней границы div. Спасибо!

P.S. Предыдущие темы на этом сайте к сожалению не подходят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите привязать действие не к нажатию кнопки, а при загрузке страницы, поставьте фукнцию загрузки документа и затем прокручивайте до нужного Вам `div`.

Пример:

```js
    window.onload = function(){ // Проверяем загрузку
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#suda').offset().top // прокручиваем страницу к требуемому элементу
            }, 500 // скорость прокрутки
        );
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Всякая всячина</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>Ещё что-нибудь</div>
<div>
    <div>И ещё</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>И ещё</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>И ещё</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>И ещё</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>И ещё</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>И ещё</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>И ещё</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>И ещё</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>И ещё</div>
</div>
<div id="suda">Прокручиваем до этого элемента с id=suda</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, чтобы страница скроллилась в обычном режиме (не автоматически как в примере) и чтобы как только скролл дойдет до "якоря",  дальше него прокручивать было нельзя (чтобы небыло видно пустоты под якорем). Моя задача просто показать пользователю содержимое до якоря, (при обычном скролле) потому что заполнять оставшееся место ниже  просто нечем. Обычно высота страницы подгоняется под содержимое, и в том что я прошу необходимости просто нет. Но в моем случае это необходимый дизайнерский ход, скажем так.

Comment: Проще говоря, получается что я хочу обрезать страницу с низу.

Comment: @WebDesighnHobbyst, возможно всё ))) Создайте вопрос, чтобы это так же могло быть полезным другим участникам, которые ищут подобный ответ. - Напишу пример.